# How To Avoid False Choice Conflict Warning in JavaCC?

Tags: javacc

Suppose I have this string to parse: ABAA and the next grammar:

```
public void parse_X() :
{}
{
  (  
     LOOKAHEAD(parse_AA())
     parse_AA()
   |
     parse_AB()
   )*
 }

public void parse_AA() :
{}
{ <A> <A> }

public void parse_AB() :
{}
{ <A> <B> }
```

It is clear that there is no ambiguity nor choice conflicts, but I'm getting one warning that claims that there is a choice conflict at line 4. My guess is that JavaCC can't remember that the LOOKAHEAD(parse_AA()) failed and therefore, a parse_AA() can't follow.

Full warning message:

> Warning: Choice conflict in (...)* construct at line 4.
>           Expansion nested within construct and expansion following construct
>           have common prefixes, one of which is: "A"
>           Consider using a lookahead of 2 or more for nested expansion. Parser generated with 0 errors and 1 warnings.

How can I avoid this warning?
Is there an alternative grammar? (Other than factorizing the common < A > )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
public void parse_X() :
{}
{
  ((  
     LOOKAHEAD(parse_AA())
     parse_AA()
   |
     parse_AB()
   ))*
 }
```

If that doesn't work, the problem is that there is something that follows an X that can start with an `<A>`.

---

Edit.

Since that didn't work, try the following:

```
public void parse_X() :
{}
{
  ( LOOKAHEAD( <A> )
   (  
     LOOKAHEAD(parse_AA())
     parse_AA()
   |
     parse_AB()
   )
  )*
 }
```

Note that all this will do is suppress the warning.  You'll have to to decided how to best deal with the ambiguity in your grammar.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work. I'm 100% sure that nothing that follows an X starts with an <A>; in fact, if I remove the kleene star, the warning disappears (but of course that is not a solution).

Comment: Maybe you're right but we differ on the JavaCC version. I'll check it on the newest and come back.

Comment: I doubt the version of JavaCC matters here.  I think the problem is that an <A> can follow and X.  In that case, JavaCC needs more than 1 token of look ahead to decide whether to exit the loop. See my editted answer.

Comment: This worked. Thanks. Yet, I'm 100% sure that <A> is only called inside parse_AA and parse_AB; parse_AA and parse_AB are only called inside parse_X, so I don't think that an <A> could follow parse_X.

Comment: Ok. Glad it worked. Sorry my original answer was wrong.  I should know better.  As to whether or not an A can follow an X, you are 100% sure that it can't, but JavaCC is 100% sure that it can!  However, JavaCC's calculation of Follow sets does not take into account what the start symbol of the grammar is, so perhaps you are both right.